# GPS location change notification

Tags: android, locationmanager

Can I receive a notification on the GPS's location change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    GlobalHelper.handler.post(GlobalHelper.update_location);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GlobalHelper.system_message(provider + " Ausgeschaltet", 0,false);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GlobalHelper.system_message(provider + " Eingeschaltet",0,false);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
    Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: what is GlobalHelper here dude, i am trying to import but it is not showing it as a class or interface or anything..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` with

```
<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
```

check here for an example

[Detecting GPS on/off switch in Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368286/detecting-gps-on-off-switch-in-android-phones)