# Detecting GPS on/off switch in Android phones

Tags: android, gps

I would like to detect when the user changes the GPS settings on or off for an Android phone.
Meaning when user switches GPS sattelite on/off or detection via access points etc.

Comment: +1, 5 marked as favorite question and only 1 upvoted?!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As I have found out the best way to do this is to attach to the

```
<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
```

intent.

For instance:

```
<receiver android:name=".gps.GpsLocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And then in the code:

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener 
...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"))
        { 
            // react on GPS provider change action 
        }
}
```

Comment: Works not only for GPS but also for network location services.

Comment: Upvoted, but why do you need `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`?

Comment: 4 years ago it was needed, I think ... who would know. Try it without if it works so much better.

Comment: for what purpose you are using `.matches()` method instead of `equals()/equalsIgnoreCase()`???

Comment: Probably it was copy pasted from some working code where .matches() was appropriate. In this case .equals() is better. But both will work. Hey it's 4+ years since then ... who would now.

Comment: you don't need implements LocationListener

Comment: @Radesh this question is 7 years old ... in 2011 you had to

Comment: For API level 26 and above, this solution doesn't work due to restrictions in implicit broadcast. It fails with "BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED } " Read More at: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions and https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 21):

Here is a code sample for a `BroadcastReceiver` detecting GPS location ON/OFF events:

```
private BroadcastReceiver locationSwitchStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (isGpsEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) {
                    //location is enabled
                } else {
                    //location is disabled
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Instead of changing your manifest file, you can register your `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
mActivity.registerReceiver(locationSwitchStateReceiver, filter);
```

Don't forget to unregister the receiver in your `onPause()` method:

```
mActivity.unregisterReceiver(locationSwitchStateReceiver);
```

Comment: It works. But why onReceive comes multiple times?

Comment: Different actions maybe. What it the value of intent.getAction() when onReceive is called ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            Log.i("About GPS", "GPS is Enabled in your devide");
        } else {
            //showAlert
        }
```

Comment: I know how to detect if a provider is on or off. But I would like to detect the change, when the user switches a provider on or off in a setting dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Impement android.location.LocationListener, there you have two functions

```
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider);
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider);
```

Using this you can find out when the requested provider is turned on or off

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer is already using LocationListener, so why not use the given methods for the task.

Comment: You can detect on/off state but you can't detect the change (switch)