# Android cannot detect the GPS switching on/off when used fake GPS before

Tags: android, gps

I have application which i use broadcast receiver to check GPS status, like this [Detecting GPS on/off switch in Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368286/detecting-gps-on-off-switch-in-android-phones) . It works well until i install and run the fake GPS app, i cannot detect GPS status anymore although i turn off the fake GPS.

Comment: in your settings, check mock location app that is used. Uninstall fake gps and try.

Comment: yes thanks, it should work well. But i just want to know if have any solution to get the GPS switching values in code in this case.

Comment: you mean you need to check if gps spoofing is on and is using some app for the same ?

Comment: @Rahull Ahuja: thanks! But I mean that i can listen the GPS on/off with broadcast receiver until I install the fake gps --> turn it on(need to turn on the Allow Mock Location in phone Setting) --> then I turn it off(dont Allow Mock Location in phone Setting) --> my app cannot listen the GPS on/off anymore. Do you why? and how's it resolved?