# how to get alert on MapActivity whenever gps is disabled by user

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

i am making an app in android using java which show current address on map and give alert whenever gps is off.

```
public class LocationManagerCheck {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Boolean locationServiceBoolean = false;
    int providerType = 0;
    static AlertDialog alert;

    public LocationManagerCheck(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (networkIsEnabled == true && gpsIsEnabled == true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 1;

        } else if (networkIsEnabled != true && gpsIsEnabled == true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 2;

        } else if (networkIsEnabled == true && gpsIsEnabled != true) {
            locationServiceBoolean = true;
            providerType = 1;
        }

    }

    public Boolean isLocationServiceAvailable() {
        return locationServiceBoolean;
    }

    public int getProviderType() {
        return providerType;
    }

    public void createLocationServiceError(final Activity activity) {

        // show alert dialog if Internet is not connected
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.setMessage(
                "You need to activate location service to use this feature. Please turn on network or GPS mode in location settings")
                .setTitle("LostyFound")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

I  am  using  this code  which only showing alert when `Mapactivity` is starts but not in during the `activity` .I just want, it's show me alert bo when gps is off or disable by user during MapActivity is open ,help me to find correct code  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to know whether the user turns ON/OFF the GPS. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368286/detecting-gps-on-off-switch-in-android-phones) may help

Answer (score 0):

For this, u have to use **Broadcast receiver**

First, you have to register broadcast

```
  private var receiverRegistered: Boolean = false

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                registerBroadcast()
        }

     private fun registerBroadcast() {
            val filter = IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED)
            this.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, filter)
            receiverRegistered = true
        }

private val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION == intent?.action) {
                val locationManager = contxt?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
                val isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                if (!isGpsEnabled) {
                    // call your alert here
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

And the most important thing unregister the broadcast receiver

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        if (receiverRegistered) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver)
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Every time user turn off the GPS it will show alert.

Comment: you can check from here to register the receiver in java https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/11834065